# Clean mysql data for XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml, loops

I am trying to loop through my MySQL data and clean it up for my XML but I am trying to do it the most efficient way possible. Below is my code so far.  This code only cleans one field `CompanyName` I want to clean all 8 fields if the same loop if possible.

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM COMPANYINFO ORDER BY CompanyName DESC"; 
$resultID = mysql_query($SQL_query, $linkID) or die("Data not found."); 

$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"; 
$xml_output .= "<markers>\n"; w

for($x = 0 ; $x < mysql_num_rows($resultID) ; $x++){ 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultID); 

            // Escaping illegal characters 
        $row['CompanyName'] = str_replace("&", "&", $row['CompanyName']); 
        $row['CompanyName'] = str_replace("<", "<", $row['CompanyName']); 
        $row['CompanyName'] = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $row['CompanyName']); 
        $row['CompanyName'] = str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $row['CompanyName']); 

    $xml_output .= "\t\t<marker name='.$row['CompanyName']."' address='".$row['Address_1']."' phone='".$row['Phone']."' lat='".$row['Lat_Info']."' lng='".$row['Long_Info']."' county='".$row['County']."'/>\n";
} 

$xml_output .= "</markers>"; 


echo $xml_output;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run any strings that you need to put in XML through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and you should be fine.

As to dealing with the results, you can use a `foreach` loop to go through the array.

Put together, you get:

```
foreach($row as $column) {
    $row[$column] = htmlspecialchars($column);
}
```

Comment: thanks your info was very helpful. I shouldn't htmlspecialchars replace "&" too? I noticed the fields with amperstands were still throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultID); 
$row = array_map('htmlentities', $row);
$xml_output .= "\t\t<marker name='.$row['CompanyName']."' address='".$row['Address_1']."' phone='".$row['Phone']."' lat='".$row['Lat_Info']."' lng='".$row['Long_Info']."' county='".$row['County']."'/>\n";
```